# Which Eclipse XML editor has an option to auto-reformat file on Save?

Tags: xml, eclipse

Eclipse has an auto-reformat option when you save .java files but I wasn't able to find one for .xml files.

I know that there are tons of XML editors for Eclipse, but which are those that can do this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question @sorin?. I have the same question.